# Does removing annotation can cause runtime crash?

Tags: java, android, performance, android-layout, annotations

Following library is causing conflicts in my Project, So i have to remove it.

> compile 'org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28'

If I remove this dependency then I have to remove these annotations from the project.

> @Generated("org.jsonschema2pojo")

As of now, Its not making any impact at both run and compile time.

But I need confirmation on this. I googled this, but I still have some confusions.

- Does these annotations make any impact on code?
  *I know they must, that's why we add them,but what impact.*
- Will removing these can cause any minor or major impact at run time? *As on compile time its not giving any warning or error message.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will not have any impact. This annotation is used mark source code that has been generated. From the [documentation.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/annotation/Generated.html)

> The Generated annotation is used to mark source code that has been generated.

**Use javax annotation**

Also, you don't need to have `org.glassfish:javax.annotation:10.0-b28` dependency in order to use the `@Generated` annotation. It comes as part of the javax packages. Just import `javax.annotation.Generated;` and you won't have to remove the annotation.

Comment: Thanks, by default it import this library `import org.parceler.Generated;`, Is it fine? Anyhow i will be removing this annotation.

Comment: remove the library. Then remove that import and replace with `import javax.annotation.Generated;` and you wont have to remove the annotation.

Comment: Thanks a lot !! :)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the type of annotation you use.  In your case `@Generated` is just a marker annotation used to signify that the piece of code was auto-generated.  Removing this will not have any impact on the behavior of your code.

Take the example of `@Autowired` annotation, this annotation is used to inject an object, removing it will definitely have implications.